# nmcli disconnect without turning wifi card off?

Tags: networking, wifi, nmcli

My wifi card keeps connecting to a wifi network which is on a channel that prevents me from making a hotspot.

I'm trying to turn the connection off from command line. I have tried a few things:

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

and

```
ifconfig wlo1 down
```

Problem with these is that they turn the wifi interface off which also prevents me from creating a hotspot.

What command can I run to keep my wifi interface on but not connected to anything?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
LANG=C nmcli d
DEVICE  TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
wlan0   wifi      connected  connectioname 
eth0    ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo      loopback  unmanaged  --
```

Here you can see the name of the connection as `connectionname`.

To disconnect, run `nmcli con down id connectionname`.

Comment: I think you can omit the `id` in the command and shorten it to: `nmcli con down connectionname`

Answer (score 3):

To Connect/disconnect existing-connected wifi:

nmcli con up "wifi name";
nmcli con down "wifi name";

To Connect/disconnect new wifi:

nmcli device wifi connect "wifi_name" password "password";
nmcli device down "con-name"   or   nmcli device disconnect "interface_name";

To Create PC hotspot(Lin):

Note:Interface i.e. wifi device not required here since wifi-interface is only used for hotspot also ,con-name must be for future
use same hotspot
<===============================================================================================================================>

nmcli device wifi hotspot ifname "interface_name" ssid "hotspot_display_name" con-name "any name to use for network" password "your_password"

nmcli device down "con-name"   or  nmcli device disconnect "interface_name";

to re-activate/deactivate existing hotspot use con-name

nmcli device up "con-name"
nmcli device down "con-name"